# How to use CSS to display all the 4 div:s content in a same place of HTML body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have  4 div:s, at a time only one div content is displayed in the specified position of the html body,  how to use css to display all the 4 div's content in a same place based on the url clicked.

If url #1 was clicked it should display the content in div #1, and so on - for 4 divs, but only one div at a time  should be displayed in the middle of the page.

## CSS

```
.viewerpane {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 560px;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="viewerpane" id="Swipe Access_viewerpane" style="position:relative"></div>
  <div class="viewerpane" id="After Office Hours_viewerpane" style="position:relative"></div>
  <div class="viewerpane" id="Weekend Access_viewerpane" style="position:relative"></div>
  <div class="viewerpane" id="All Users Data_viewerpane" style="position:relative"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need JavaScript for that, and you would find it much easier if your IDs were valid; IDs cannot contain spaces. In addition to this, you'll probably want to use relative units (such as percentages) for your `width` and `height` in the CSS -- otherwise you'll only be able to see the text on desktop computers.

Comment: try using tabs.

Comment: While usually done with JS, tabs can be done with CSS-only, [for example](https://kyusuf.com/post/completely-css-tabs).

Comment: thanks a lot @charankumar :) , it worked for  me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onclick` to `a` and in function [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) or [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) selector by his `id`(without space)

```js
function func(id){
$('.viewerpane').hide();
$('#'+id).show();
}
```

```css
    .viewerpane {
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-left: 100px;
      width: 1200px;
      height: 560px;
    }
    a{
    display:block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="func('Swipe_Access_viewerpane')">Swipe_Access_viewerpane</a>
<a href="#" onclick="func('After_Office_Hours_viewerpane')">After_Office Hours_viewerpane</a>
<a href="#" onclick="func('Weekend_Access_viewerpane')">Weekend_Access_viewerpane</a>
<a href="#" onclick="func('All_Users_Data_viewerpane')">All_Users_Data_viewerpane</a>
<div class="row">
      <div class="viewerpane" id="Swipe_Access_viewerpane" style="position:relative">Swipe_Access_viewerpane</div>
      <div class="viewerpane" id="After_Office_Hours_viewerpane" style="position:relative">After_Office Hours_viewerpane</div>
      <div class="viewerpane" id="Weekend_Access_viewerpane" style="position:relative">Weekend_Access_viewerpane</div>
      <div class="viewerpane" id="All_Users_Data_viewerpane" style="position:relative">All_Users_Data_viewerpane</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: that what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS only solution for this.

```css
div,
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:hover {
  color: red;
}

label:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

#n1:checked~.n1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

#n2:checked~.n2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

#n3:checked~.n3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

#n4:checked~.n4 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="sel" id="n1"><label for="n1">Link 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="sel" id="n2"><label for="n2">Link 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="sel" id="n3"><label for="n3">Link 3</label>
<input type="radio" name="sel" id="n4"><label for="n4">Link 4</label>

<div class="n1">
  <p>Option 1</p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div class="n2">
  <p>Option 2</p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div class="n3">
  <p>Option 3</p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div class="n4">
  <p>Option 4</p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="viewerpane hidden" id="Swipe_Access_viewerpane">
    <p>test data1</p> 
  </div>
  <div class="viewerpane hidden" id="After_Office_Hours_viewerpane">
    <p>test data2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="viewerpane hidden" id="Weekend_Access_viewerpane">
    <p>test data3</p> 
  </div>
  <div class="viewerpane hidden" id="All_Users_Data_viewerpane">
    <p>test data4</p> 
  </div>
</div>      
<a id="click-me">click here to see the effect</a>
```

css

```
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 900px;
 }
.viewerpane {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 560px; 
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%)  translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%)  translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-50%)  translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-50%)  translateX(-50%);
  display: table;
}
.viewerpane p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

javasript:

```
let divs_to_show;
let index = 0;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(e) 
{
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('viewerpane');
divs_to_show = Array.from(divs);
showDiv(); 
});

document.querySelector('#click-me').addEventListener('click', changeDiv);

function changeDiv(e) 
{ 
 divs_to_show.forEach(div => 
  {
   div.className = 'viewerpane hidden';
  });
  showDiv();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function showDiv() 
{
 divs_to_show[index].className = 'viewerpane';index++;
}
```

see the live example here https://codepen.io/kamindu/pen/bxGxqZ